# ¿Que función tiene el "(e)" en los códigos Js?

Tags: javascript

Comprendo el programa pero no se exactamente que es

> (e)

El programa consiste en mostrar las coordenadas del puntero sobre la página.

## HTML

```
<html>
<head>
 <script src="DH18.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 <p id="cx">
  Coordenada x=
 </p>
 <p id="cy">
  Coordenada y=
 </p>
</body>
</html>
```

### JS

```
   window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

    function iniciar(e){
    var cuerpo=document.getElementsByTagName('html');
    cuerpo[0].addEventListener('mousemove', coord, false);
    }

    function coord(e){
    var cx=document.getElementById('cx');
    var cy=document.getElementById('cy');
    cx.firstChild.nodeValue='Coordenada x='+' '+e.clientX;
    cy.firstChild.nodeValue='Coordenada y='+' '+e.clientY;
   }
```

Comment: Es el evento :)

Comment: Si yo no pusiera el (e), el programa no funcionaria. No obstante tengo varios ejercicios en los que empleo el evento 'click', 'mouseup', etc,  y no utilizo el (e)

Comment: Muchas veces no es necesario usar el evento mismo para cumplir una determinada tarea, como en tu función `iniciar(e)`, otras veces si lo necesitas para sacar las coordemadas, por ejemplo, en tu función `coord(e)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Me explico. Cuando usas [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) lo que haces es "escuchar" (del inglés "listen") los eventos de un elemento. Cuando este evento es "escuchado" (cuando ocurre) le pasas el control a una función "escuchadora" (no se me ocurre otro nombre, del inglés "listener"). Al pasarle el control a esta función es posible que le pases el evento mismo que ha sido "escuchado".

Con un ejemplo:

```js
 window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

 function iniciar() {
     var boton = document.getElementById('boton');
     boton.addEventListener('click', clickBoton, false);
 }

 function clickBoton(evento) {
     console.log(evento.target);
 }
```

```html
<button id="boton">Prueba</button>
```

El primer evento que escuchamos en mi ejemplo es el `load`, es decir, cuando carga la página. Ahora, es posible que la función `iniciar` decida si recibir este parámetro o no, si no vamos a usar el evento no hay problema, por lo tanto la definición de la función podría ser una de las dos:

```
function iniciar() {
    // ...
}

function iniciar(evento) {
    // ...
}
```

Esto responde a tu comentario y es la razón por la cual puedes decidir si recibir o no el evento en tu función (y funciona sin el evento como tú bien mencionas):

> No obstante tengo varios ejercicios en los que empleo el evento
>   'click', 'mouseup', etc, y no utilizo el (e)

En el segundo caso, escucho el evento `click` del botón, en este caso sí quiero recibir el evento para poder mostrarte una de las propiedades de este evento, la propiedad `target` que no es más que el elemento del cual el evento ha sido "escuchado", si ves el resultado del `console.log()` podrás ver que imprime el HTML del botón.

Así como la propiedad `target`, existen muchas otras propiedades y funciones en el [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event).

Answer (score 4):

El `e` representa un evento.

La [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Reference/Events) define los eventos del siguiente modo:

> Los eventos se envían para notificar al código de cosas interesantes
>   que han ocurrido. Cada evento está representado por un objeto que se
>   basa en la interfaz [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/Event), y puede tener campos y/o funciones
>   personalizadas adicionales para obtener más información acerca de lo
>   sucedido. Los eventos pueden representar cualquier cosa desde las
>   interacciones básicas del usuario para notificaciones automatizadas de
>   las cosas que suceden en el modelo de representación.

La forma más sencilla de crear un evento es hacer clic en algún lugar de la página.

Al hacer clic, un evento de clic se activa. Este evento es en realidad un objeto que contiene información sobre la acción que acaba de suceder. En el caso de este ejemplo:

```
window.addEventListener('load', iniciar, false);

function iniciar(e)
{
   var cuerpo=document.getElementsByTagName('html');
   cuerpo[0].addEventListener('mousemove', coord, false);
}
```

el evento tendría información sobre la ventana (window), el elemento en el que se hizo clic (event.target) y mucho más.

#### ¿Hay que usar siempre `e`?

En los programas actuales, podemos decir que los eventos ocurren todo el tiempo, sin embargo en algunos casos puede no estar interesado en los eventos que suceden.
Solamente agregas un detector de eventos al elemento que sabes que creará eventos si tienes interés en manejar alguno de esos eventos. Por ejemplo, estás interesado en saber cuando el usuario hace clic en un botón "Suscribir" y deseas hacer algo cuando sucede este evento.

Para hacer algo sobre este evento, enlazas un controlador de eventos al botón que te interesa. La forma de enlazar el controlador al elemento es haciendo :

```
element.addEventListener (eventName, handler).
```

`EventName` es el nombre del evento en el que estás interesado, que en este caso sería '`click`' (para el evento click).

El manejador es simplemente una función que hace algo (se ejecuta) cuando sucede el evento. La función de controlador, de forma predeterminada, acepta como argumento el objeto de evento que se creó cuando ocurrió el evento / acción que le interesa. Éste es el `e` que ves en las funciones mencionadas en tu pregunta.

Definir el evento como un parámetro de su función de manejador es opcional, sin embargo, a veces (la mayoría de las veces) es útil que la función del manejador sepa sobre el evento que sucedió. Recuerda, el evento es sólo un objeto javascript regular, con muchas propiedades en él.

Para más información:

- [`element.addEventListener` en la documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)
- [Creación y desencadenamiento de eventos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/DOM/Events/Creacion_y_Activaci%C3%B3n_Eventos)

---

Fuente: [Javascript: what exactly is parameter e(event) and why pass it to javascript function?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35936912/5587982)

Answer (score 3):

Básicamente `(e)` es un objeto de tipo evento.

Cuando el evento `load` sea ejecutado, llamara a la función `iniciar` con un argumento de tipo evento en el cual estara toda la informacion relacionada con el evento y el elemento.

#### Algunas propiedades que tendra el evento `load` son:

- `Target`: **EventTarget** - El destino del evento (el objetivo superior del árbol DOM)
- `Type`: **String** - Tipo de evento
- `Cancelable`: **Boolean** - Si el evento es cancelable

#### Algunas propiedades que tendra el evento [mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove) son:

- `clientX`: **Long** - La coordenada X del puntero del ratón en local.
- `ctrlKey / shiftKey / altKey`: **Boolean** - True si la tecla estaba activada cuando se disparó el evento

#### Recursos

- [Evento mousemove](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/mousemove)

Answer (score 3):

En `function miFuncion(e){...}` lo que se encuentra entre paréntesis son los parámetros, también llamados argumentos, de la función de nombre `miFuncion`. Es común encontrar que se usa `e` como nombre de parámetro que se refiere a un evento, por ser la inicial de `event`, término en inglés que se traduce como evento.

Algunas funciones como  `window.addEventListener`, lo que hacen es crear otras funciones. En el caso de `addEventListener` se crea un "oyente" o monitor que al ocurrir un evento llaman la función especificada pasando a esta un objeto como parámetro. En este caso se trata de un objeto que incluye propiedades que describen lo sucedido.

Si en el enunciado de declaración de la función no se incluye de forma explítica la `e` o cualquier otro nombre de parámetro, de todas formas se podría hacer referencia al objeto enviado usando la propiedad `arguments`, sin embargo, esto ha sido desaprobado y aunque algunos navegadores aún lo soportan podría dejar de hacerlo en cualquier momento.

Referencias

- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/function
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Function/arguments
- https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 3):

Todos los eventos en javascript van acompañados de un objeto event que trae toda la información del evento, por ejmplo, coordenadas del mouse, coordenadas de donde se hizo click, que tecla fue presionada, etc.

Ese objeto evento se maneja un tanto diferente entre el revelde IE y FireFox o Chrome.

En IE el objeto event es un obeto global y puedes acceder a el directamente poniendo `Event.agluna_propiedad` en cualquier evento, sin embargo en FF y Chrome no existe un objeto global llamado Event, javascript pasa éste objeto como argumento a la función que se dispara con el evento, por lo tanto, cuando creas la funcion que manejará el evento tienes que ponerle un argumento donde va a viajar el objeto event y como cualquier nombre de argumente lo puedes nombrar como quieras: **e, evt,evento,x, etc**.

Por eso te vas a encontrar funciones como las siguientes

```
function miClick(e){
    var evento = Event || e; //Obtienes el evento segun el explorador
}
```

Lo que sucede es que tienes una variable llamada evento la cual va a obtener el objeto event dependiendo del explorador. 
Si existe el objeto global Event, la variable evento va a tomar ese objeto
Si no existe se tomara como falso y se evaluará la siguiente expresion del OR  (||) que es la `e` que viene de los parametros y que FireFox y Chrome pusieron un event ahí.

Comment: Excelente!!! (+1). Amena, puntual, breve, sencilla y clara explicación de lo que se pregunta, felicidades!!! ;))...

Comment: Muchas gracias.